# Is there an Issue with the MS example for SQLDataReader.GetBytes Example

Tags: c#

The code below, shows a part of the MS Help example for retrieving binary data

```
// Read bytes into outByte[] and retain the number of bytes returned.
retval = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);

// Continue while there are bytes beyond the size of the buffer.
while (retval == bufferSize)
{
  writer.Write(outByte);
  writer.Flush();

  // Reposition start index to end of last buffer and fill buffer.
  startIndex += bufferSize;
  retval = reader.GetBytes(1, startIndex, outByte, 0, bufferSize);
}

// Write the remaining buffer.
writer.Write(outByte, 0, (int)retval - 1);
writer.Flush();
```

When I use this, if the input data is an exact multiple of bufferSize, the last write evaluates to -1 and raises an exception.  Am I doing something wrong or is the example incorrect?  I can test for remaining data before attempting the last write, but if there is a preferred way of doing this than offered by the example I am all ears.

Thanks

Comment: [link to the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87z0hy49%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I get the same problem. It also seems to miss the last byte of my data. Looks to me like someone was incredibly sloppy building that page.

Comment: If this is a definite bug, look for the "Was this page helpful?" section at the bottom.  You can click "No" and give details.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for how to do it, here's how I would suggest:

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(myConnectionString))
{
    conn.Open();
    using (var comm = conn.CreateCommand())
    {
        comm.CommandText = "select somedata from Foo";
        using (var rdr = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            using (var fs = File.Create(@"C:\temp\myfile.bin"))
            {
                const int BUFFER_SIZE = 2048;
                var buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
                long offset = 0L;

                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    int count;
                    while ((count = (int)rdr.GetBytes(0, offset, buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE)) > 0)
                    {
                        fs.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                        offset += count;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The example on that MDSN page is full of issues - I wouldn't even try to salvage it.

Comment: Answer one worked fine thanks. I am glad to know it was the example that had the issue. Subtle too. It took 3 months and over 1.8M documents being fetched until we hit one on a boundary.